# Scala. Future в гварде

Tags: scala, future

Существует ли способ подождать выполнения футуры внутри гварда?
Не внутри `case` блока или за пределами блока `Try`:

```
import scala.util.Try
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main extends App {
  val f = Future {
    Thread.sleep(999999)
    true
  }

  Try (1) match {
    case x if f => println("Waited for future")  // Here
    case _ => println(":(")
  }
}
```

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: А что такое « внутри гварда»? :-)))

Comment: @avgolubev Значит где-то между началом и окончанием охранного выражения. :-))) В примере это `f` в `if f =>`

Comment: Спасибо, точно - guard :-)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ есть, но самому ждать фьючу - антипатерн. Вот он:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.language.postfixOps

Try (1) match {
  case x if Await.result(f, 10 hours) => println("Waited for future")  // Here
  case _ => println(":(")
}
```

Обрати внимание что ждать придётся долго из-за `Thread.sleep(999999)`.

А вот более кошерный способ:

```
f.foreach { resultOfF =>
  Try(1) match {
    case x if resultOfF => println("Waited for future") // Here
    case _ => println(":(")
  }
}
```

Только в твоём примере я бы заменил дефолтный `ExecutionContext` на свой. Потому что дефолтный не ждёт результата фьюч.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}
import scala.util.Try

object Main extends App {
  val ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
  implicit val exec: ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())

  val f = Future {
    Thread.sleep(10000)
    true
  }

  f.map { resultOfF =>
    Try(1) match {
      case x if resultOfF => println("Waited for future") // Here
      case _ => println(":(")
    }
  }.onComplete(_ => ex.shutdown())
}
```